# Processing data that could be an array or a single value, without conditional

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `data` that could be either a single value (let's say it could be object, string, or number) or an array.  I want to execute a function on every element of the array, or on the single value.  Currently, I have:

```
let result;
if (Array.isArray(data)) {
   result = data.map(d => f(d))
} else {
   result = f(data);
}
```

I could use a ternary to the same effect, but I'd like to remove the conditional.  Is there an idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: a ternary is a conditional. Not clear what you're trying to do. `result = Array.isArray(data) ? data.map(f) : f(data);` should produce the same result you have. It's sounds like code smell to me. I'd expect result to always be the same type but possible allow a single element or multiple elements. In that case it might do something like `result = (Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data]).map(f);`

Comment: Right - I'd like to do it w/ out ternary.  Is that possible?

Comment: Short of ensuring the data is an array, I don't see how this would be possible

Comment: I don't think so because that's not a standard case - why can't you just make the input to be consistent, and always return an array even when there's only one element?

Comment: There is a peasant way to transform everything to array using `JSON.stringify` and then check the array inside your `map` but you would complicate things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional dimension and use `.flat()` to get rid of it

```
[5].flat() // [5]
[[5]].flat() // [5]
```

this way you can write:

```
[data].flat().map(f);
```

but it doesn't make sense and just wastes computional time; conditional should be faster here.

Try to just make your input consistent and always pass an array to this place (even with single element).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an "esoteric looking" `function` I call `fmap` in this example (although the name isn't really correct):

```js
function fmap (f, x) {
  return (function (g) {
    return g(f);
  })((x && x.map && x.map.bind(x)) || function (h) { return h(x); });
}

const upper = x => x.toUpperCase();

console.log('fmap over array:', fmap(upper, ['a', 'b', 'c']));
console.log('fmap over string:', fmap(upper, 'a'));
```

**WTF??**

`fmap` takes a function and a value (`f` and `x`). It invokes an IIFE to determine if the value `x` already implements a `map` method. If it does, it binds that `map` method to the value. If the value doesn't implement a `map` method, it creates an anonymous function which takes in another function and calls that other function with the value `x`.

Finally, it returns the result of the computation.

**Further thoughts**

To be honest, my personal opinion is to *use a conditional*! It is *much easier to understand* and to reason about. Anyway, it is doable without a conditional statement or the ternary operator.